# Recursive binary search function in C++

Tags: c++, binary-search

I'm writing a recursive binary search function for a project in C++ and for some reason, it runs infinitely and does not execute properly. My code is as follows:

```
int recursiveBin(const int list[], int listLength, int searchItem)
{
    if(listLength == 0)
        return -1;

    int mid = (listLength - 1)/2;

    if(list[mid] > searchItem)
        return recursiveBin(list, mid - 1, searchItem);
    else if(list[mid] < searchItem)
        return recursiveBin(list, mid + 1, searchItem);
    else
        return mid;
}
```

Can someone please help me with this? I'm not sure what is going wrong with my function and where the infinite loop comes.

Comment: Take a piece of paper - create sample input - and write down what happens.  Figure out at what point it goes wrong and fix.

Answer (score 2):

Add one more parameter to store the search boundary.

```
int recursiveBin(const int list[], int start, int end, int searchItem)
{
    if(end > start)
        return -1;

    int mid = (start + end)/2;

    if(list[mid] > searchItem)
        return recursiveBin(list, start, mid - 1, searchItem);
    else if(list[mid] < searchItem)
        return recursiveBin(list, mid + 1, end, searchItem);
    else
        return mid;
}
```

Comment: Or when searching the upper range, pass `list + mid + 1` and `listLength - mid - 1` as the length parameter.